# Android Spinner : spinner arrow displayed and blinking when scrolling

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, spinner

I am developing an Android application in Kotlin and I implemented a RecyclerView.

Each item of this RecyclerView contains one of the 3 combinations below:

- a `TextView` + a `TextView`
- a `TextView` + a `Button`
- a `TextView` + a `Spinner`

In this activity, I have initialized my parameter list and I can add parameters of one of the 3 types mentioned above by clicking on the `TEST` button.

My problem is a UI problem: when there are a lot of parameters containing Spinners such that you have to scroll to see them, an arrow of a spinner is displayed at the very top of the RecyckerView (or at the very bottom sometimes). This spinner arrow starts flashing when I scroll and finally stops after a few seconds. Please note that I can't click on this arrow. I don't understand my mistake, can you help me?

[Here](https://youtu.be/bRGaFHX0TZE) is a link to a Youtube video recording of the behavior I have described that will help you better understand it.

Here is my view when I am on top of my RecyclerView:

[image]

This is my view when I scrolled down in the RecyclerView and there are parameters containing Spinners that are only visible when scrolling up again.

[image]

Here is my **CustomAdapter** class:

```
class CustomAdapter(private var parameterList: List<Parameter>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    sealed class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        class TextViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val textViewValue: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterValue)
        }
        class ButtonViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            var textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val buttonViewValue: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterButton)
        }
        class SpinnerViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val spinnerViewValue: Spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterSpinner)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            0 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_text, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.TextViewHolder(view)
            }
            1 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_button, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.ButtonViewHolder(view)
            }
            2 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_spinner, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.SpinnerViewHolder(view)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (viewHolder) {
            is ViewHolder.TextViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = parameterList[position].parameterName
                viewHolder.textViewValue.text = parameterList[position].parameterValue as CharSequence?
            }
            is ViewHolder.ButtonViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = parameterList[position].parameterName
                viewHolder.buttonViewValue.text = parameterList[position].parameterValue as CharSequence?
            }
            is ViewHolder.SpinnerViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = parameterList[position].parameterName
                viewHolder.spinnerViewValue.adapter = parameterList[position].parameterValue as SpinnerAdapter?
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) : Int {
        return parameterList[position].parameterType
    }


    override fun getItemCount() = parameterList.size

    fun addNewList(newList: List<Parameter>){
        parameterList = newList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Each of the different types of parameters inherited from the class **Parameter**:

```
open class Parameter(open var parameterName: String? = "", open var parameterType: Int = 0, open var parameterValue: Any) {
}
```

**ParameterText** class:

```
class ParameterText(override var parameterName: String?, override var parameterValue: Any = "") : Parameter(parameterName, parameterValue = parameterValue!!) {
    override var parameterType: Int = 0
}
```

**ParameterButton** class:

```
class ParameterButton(override var parameterName: String?, override var parameterValue: Any = "") : Parameter(parameterName, parameterValue = parameterValue!!) {
    override var parameterType: Int = 1
}
```

**ParameterSpinner** class:

```
class ParameterSpinner(override var parameterName: String?, override var parameterValue: Any) : Parameter(parameterName, parameterValue = parameterValue) {
    override var parameterType: Int = 2
}
```

Here is my **NFCActivity**:

```
class NFCActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc)

        buttonTest.setOnClickListener() {

            parametersList = parametersList +                 ParameterSpinner(
                    "Led", ArrayAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, resources.getStringArray(R.array.LedState)
            )
            )
            (rv_parameters2.adapter as CustomAdapter).addNewList(parametersList)
        }

        rv_parameters2.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rv_parameters2.adapter = CustomAdapter(parametersList)
    }

    private var parametersList : List<Parameter> = listOf<Parameter> (
            ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C"),
            ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
    )

    companion object {
        fun getStartIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            return Intent(context, NFCActivity::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**NFCActivity**'s layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.ble.NFCActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_parameters2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/parameter_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonTest"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I am seeing something like this too... did you work out what the problem was?

Comment: No sorry I couldn't find what the problem was..

Comment: So are you still seeing the flickering or did you make other changes (e.g. layout changes) that made the problem go away, even if you don't know what the problem was?

Comment: In fact, I don't use that much Spinner in the latest version of my application. The case of the flashing spinner arrow seems to be related to the fact that there are many spinners.